# What is the occasional +1 rep for?

Tags: discussion, reputation

On and off, I'll get +1 rep for seemingly no reason. It doesn't show up in the "Reputation" section on one's profile, and I haven't been able to find an action that produces this repeatedly.

No complaints, cause I like to use it as a freebie downvote...I'm slightly OCD and like having a rep of 0 mod 5. :)

Still, anyone know where it comes from?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you go to your reputation page in your profile and scroll all the way to the bottom, there should be a little checkbox labelled "show removed posts". Check that and you will see any posts that affected your reputation by virtue of their deletion.

In your case, the +1 is likely from an answer that you downvoted which was then subsequently deleted, either by the owner or by a moderator. You get the 1 rep cost of the downvote back when the answer is deleted.

Comment: impressively quick response @eldarerathis ! I can't accept your response for another minute :)

Comment: @jlehenbauer: Well, mods get a notification in their global inbox for each new question on their Meta site. You just happened to ask this right before I clicked on a Stack Overflow link from Google :P

Comment: Lightning fast cat reflexes, he means :D